# Fatal error: Call to a member function get_queried_object_id()

Tags: hooks, fatal-error, get-the-id

I am trying to display shortcode using the following pattern:

```
    class callShortCode {


    function __construct() {
    global $post;
    $this->dos($post);
    }


    private function dos($post){
    global $post;
    $pid = get_the_ID();
    $archive_id = get_queried_object_id();

    if($archive_id == $pid) {
    add_action('wp_footer', array($this, 'show'));
    }

    }


    // shortcode call
    function show($post) {

    $pid = get_the_ID();
    $archive_id = get_queried_object_id();


    $the_query = new WP_Query( array('post_type' => 'custom_post_type') );
                    if ($the_query->have_posts()) {
                        while ($the_query->have_posts()){
                        $the_query->the_post();
                          if($pid == $archive_id) {
                            echo do_shortcode("[my_shortcode id='5']");
                          }
                        }
                    }

    }

    }

new callShortCode();
```

But it is returning error like this on the front end:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function get_queried_object_id() on a non-object in D:\xxxx\xxxx\xxxxx\wp-includes\query.php on line xx
```

I have try to wrap it up with `init` action but it don't want read the current page id on the front-end and show nothing. I have checked that the `$pid = get_the_ID();` and `$archive_id = get_queried_object_id();` is returning 0 when I used the `init` hook to call the object.

I also wrapped it up using `plugins_loaded` but it is returning the same fatal error!

I know it is because it is called too early! But what can I do to make it working correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instantiate your object inside a function hooked to the `template_redirect` action:

```
function wpse_177056_init_shortcode() {
    new callShortCode();
}

add_action( 'template_redirect', 'wpse_177056_init_shortcode' );
```

Comment: Thanks, it works! How about the performance?

Comment: Performance? Compared to instantiating immediately? No difference even worth mentioning.

Answer (score 1):

The ID of the current object is available only after the actual main query has been executed. Also, `get_queried_object_id()` uses the `global $wp_query` object; if this object has not been set up, calling some of its methods or properties won't work.

So, you must use `get_queried_object_id()` later. According with [the codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference), the action hook `wp` is the first available after the WP object has been set up. In your case you can use also `wp_footer` action directly as it is when you are trying to execute the shortcode:

```
class callShortCode {

    function __construct() {
        $this->dos();
    }

  function dos() {
        $archive_id = get_queried_object_id();
        //Replace with your logic
        if( $archive_id === 451) {
            $this->show();
        }
   }

   // shortcode call
   function show() {

      $the_query = new WP_Query( array('post_type' => 'custom_post_type') );
      if ($the_query->have_posts()) {
          while ($the_query->have_posts()){
              $the_query->the_post();
                   echo do_shortcode("[my_shortcode id='5']");
           }
       }

      wp_reset_postdata();

   }
}

add_action( 'wp_footer', function() {
    new callShortCode;
});
```

**Note**: I've removed the checing of `$pid == $archive_id` because actually I don't understand your logic: your using `$pid = get_the_ID();` and `get_the_ID()` should return the same velue of `get_queried_object_id()` in single post view.